# Photos to PDF with cropping - Software similar to OfficeLens

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-editor, pdf-generation

Before Windows disabled key features I could use OfficeLens on my **desktop/laptop to open images of documents, crop, and save as PDF**. That's all I need.

Any *free* or *one-time* purchase replacements?

I utilize other free software to print PDFs. This let's me edit PDF pages (delete, move pages). If there is a purchase option, simple apps with both options would be ideal.

**Simple use case**. I have photos of invoices, and just need to save them as PDF. It's nice to clean them up with cropping. That's why free Office Lens was ideal.

#### EDIT: Sorry peeps. I should have stipulated the type of cropping

Non-rectangle cropping where you can drag the corners (OfficeLens even had an edge detection tool which followed contours that corrected for non-flat documents.). I can already crop with MS Paint and print to PDF. What I need to do is crop skewed document photos.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) lets you save images as PDF. Cropping images is also supported.

Comment: Sorry. I mistakenly didn't describe the type of crop. i need skewed cropping. I searched the Forum and reviewed tabs on the website, but I didn't find this. Does InfanView support this?

Comment: I do not think this kind of crop is available.

Answer (score 0):

[Xodo](https://www.xodo.com) is completely free and supports these two tasks.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/xodo-pdf-reader-editor/9wzdncrdjxp4

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also, Sorry I didn't describe the type of cropping. I have document photos which are often taken at an angle (see example above). I tried the link and the website version of the app (perfectly simple GUI), but I didn't find a skew crop feature. Do you know if they have this feature?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, no. This looks like the Xodo feature request here (for Android): http://feedback.xodo.com/forums/241992-suggest-a-new-feature/suggestions/41450893-suggestion-to-add-stretch-and-skew-mode-for-crop in case you want to vote.